# Same methods, different enums, how to design a parent class?

Tags: java, inheritance, enums, abstract

My two Type classes called SearchType and ResultcodeType need a parent class in an elegant way. How to design these two classes and a parent class both inherit from in an clean and code saving way?

```
public enum SearchType {
    BARCODE(0),
    TEXT(1);

    SearchType(int i)
    {
        this.type = i;
    }

    private int type;

    public static SearchType getType(int value) {
        for (SearchType searchType : SearchType.values()) {
            if (searchType.type == value)
                return searchType;
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("SearchType not found.");
    }

    public int getNumericType() {
        return type;
    }
}
```

and

```
public enum ResultcodeType {
    RESULTS(0),
    NO_RESULTS(1),
    PROBLEMS(2),
    NO_VALUE(-1);

    ResultcodeType(int i)
    {
        this.type = i;
    }

    private int type;

    public static ResultcodeType getType(int value) {
        for (ResultcodeType resultcodeType : ResultcodeType.values()) {
            if (resultcodeType.type == value)
               return resultcodeType;
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("ResultcodeType not found.");
    }

    public int getNumericType() {
        return type;
    }
}
```

**Where do I use SearchType / ResultCodeType?**

Layout Data Binding

```
<ImageView
    app:srcCompat="@{item.searchType == SearchType.BARCODE ? @drawable/ic_barcode : @drawable/ic_one_loupe}" 
/>
```

Room database converter class (where there is redundancy again). But for now room can't handle generic types in it's TypeConverter. So this will stay as is.

```
@TypeConverter
public static SearchType SearchTypeFromInt(Integer value) {
    return SearchType.getType(value);
}

@TypeConverter
public static ResultcodeType ResultcodeTypeFromInt(Integer value) {
    return ResultcodeType.getType(value);
}
```

POJO (with room annotation)

```
@NonNull
@ColumnInfo(name = "resultcode", defaultValue="-1")
private ResultcodeType mResultcode;
```

Comment: Why do they need a parent class?  In Java, enums can't inherit from another class, only from interfaces.

Comment: @rgettman they share the same methods - lots of redundancy of course.

Comment: Just curious.  Why are you using some `int value` and then trying to find the `enum type` for that value?  Why not just use the enum itself in your class?  That is what they are for.

Comment: @WJS I am saving the int values to a room database.

Comment: @S.Gissel do they share the same code because they are semantically bound or do they share code "by accident" (i.e. are both implementation giuaranteed to change in the same manner or is there a possibility that only one implementation has to change or both have to change, but differently)? If they share by accident, don't couple them by introducing abstraction.

Comment: Both classes have the same functionality. The represent the enum for high level code and when it comes to saving the values to the room database I can get the int too save in db. If other types get introduced in the future they will need the same converter methods.

Comment: Don't bake-in the conversion into the `Enum`. Write a separate `Converter` for them.  The more information you reveal, the more I get the feeling that `Enum` is not the right construct ([XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?). Could you explain what exactly the `Enum`s are used for?

Comment: I really can't think of a good way to do this using enums.  Are you required to use them?  Why not just a map with a integer key and a string value value?  Can you provide more information on what you;re trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Turing85 Edited my question to explain where my Types are used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since enums cannot have base classes, I think this is the closest you're going to get:

```
public interface Typed {
    int getNumericType();

    static <E extends Enum<E> & Typed> E getType(E[] values, int type) {
        for (E value : values)
            if (value.getNumericType() == type)
                return value;
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(values[0].getClass().getSimpleName() +
                                           " not found: " + type);
    }
}
```

```
public enum SearchType implements Typed {
    BARCODE(0),
    TEXT(1);

    private final int type;

    private SearchType(int type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public int getNumericType() {
        return this.type;
    }

    public static SearchType getType(int type) {
        return Typed.getType(values(), type);
    }
}
```

```
public enum ResultcodeType implements Typed {
    RESULTS(0),
    NO_RESULTS(1),
    PROBLEMS(2),
    NO_VALUE(-1);

    private final int type;

    private ResultcodeType(int type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public int getNumericType() {
        return this.type;
    }

    public static ResultcodeType getType(int type) {
        return Typed.getType(values(), type);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your enums could implement an interface and add default method.

For example:

```
interface Typed {
   Typed getType(int value) 

public enum ResultcodeType implements Typed {
    public Typed getType(int value) {
        for (ResultcodeType resultcodeType : 
        ResultcodeType.values()) {
            if (resultcodeType.type == value)
               return resultcodeType;
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("ResultcodeType not found.");
    }


.... 
}
```

Comment: I was thinking of genetics in the parent class to accept ResultCodeType and Searchtype and potentially others and not implement the same lines of code of eg getType in every derived class.

Comment: @S.Gissel by "genetics" you mean "generic"?

Comment: @Turing85 No I mean Generics.

Answer (score 0):

I also suggest the following approach using a map instead of searching.  In fact, all you need is the mapping.  You wouldn't even need to supply a value.  Note that you can't reference a static value from within a constructor so you have to build the map externally.

```java
   enum SearchType {
      BARCODE(0), TEXT(1), UNKNOWN(-1);
      static Map<Integer, SearchType> map =
            Map.of(0, SearchType.BARCODE, 1, SearchType.TEXT);

      SearchType(int i) {
         this.type = i;
      }

      private int type;

      public static SearchType getType(int value) {
         return SearchType.map.getOrDefault(value, SearchType.UNKNOWN);
      }

      public int getNumericType() {
         return type;
      }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      System.out.println(SearchType.getType(0));
      System.out.println(SearchType.getType(1));
      System.out.println(SearchType.getType(99));

   }
```